# Calling destructor of Inherited class from singleton class C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class which is singleton and it is abstract. So basically I am instantiating with one of the inherited class. I have constructor and destructor of abstract as protected. I want to have  base class where some of the functions have definition and some of them are pure virtual and subclasses implementing methods in that interface, but I want it to be singleton.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Base {
    protected:
        Base() {}
        virtual ~Base() { 
            cout<< "base class destructor \n";
        } 
    private:
        static Base *instance;

    public:
        virtual void overrideMe() = 0;
        static Base* getinstance(const char*);
        static void resetInstance(){
            delete instance;
        }
        virtual void testmethod();

};
class Derived1 : public Base{
    friend class Base;
    protected:
        Derived1(){
            cout<<" in Derived1 constructor \n";
        }
        virtual ~Derived1(){
            cout<< "in Derived1 destructor \n";
        }

    public:
        void overrideMe(){
            cout<< "in Derived1 \n";
        }
         void testmethod(){
             cout<< "testmethod of Derived1 \n ";
             overrideMe();
         }
};
class Derived2 : public Base{
    friend class Base;
    protected:
            Derived2(){
            cout<<" in Derived2 constructor \n";
        }
        virtual ~Derived2(){
            cout<< "in Derived2 destructor \n";
        }
    public:

        void overrideMe(){
            cout<< "in Derived2 \n";
        }
        void testmethod(){
            cout<< "testmethod of Derived2 \n ";
            overrideMe();
        }


};
Base* Base::instance = NULL;

void Base::testmethod() {
    cout << "Testing :)\n";
}

Base* Base::getinstance(const char* type) {
    if(instance == NULL){
        if(std::strcmp(type, "Derived1") == 0)
            instance = new Derived1();
        if(std::strcmp(type, "Derived2") == 0)
            instance = new Derived2();
    } 
    return instance;
}


int main() {

    Base *instanceA = Base::getinstance("Derived1"); 
  //  Derived1* ob = new Derived1();
    instanceA->testmethod();
    Base::resetInstance();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any better way of achieving the same thing as above?

Comment: It's easier to answer if you post some code, including the instantiation. (Without all the functions that aren't relevant.)

Comment: On a side note, a public constructor in the subclass defeats the singleton-ness of the base class.

Comment: Are you calling any virtual functions inside a constructor?

Comment: @molbdnilo added code

Comment: Imo, base class should not know anything about her children

Comment: @KrzysztofBargieł I know this is getting ugly, but please suggest me better way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton header:

```
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>

template <typename T>
class Singleton {
 public:
  Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
  const Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;

  static T& getInstance() {
    std::call_once(m_flag, [] { m_instance.reset(new T); });
    return *m_instance.get();
  }

 protected:
  Singleton() {}

 private:
  static std::unique_ptr<T> m_instance;
  static std::once_flag m_flag;
};

template <typename T>
std::once_flag Singleton<T>::m_flag;

template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> Singleton<T>::m_instance;
```

Your Class (singleton):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Singleton.hpp"



class YourInterface {
public:
    virtual void Hello() = 0;
    virtual ~YourInterface() {}
};

class YourClass : public YourInterface, public Singleton<YourClass> {
  friend class Singleton<YourClass>;

 public:
    virtual void Hello () {std::cout << "Hello form YourClass\n";}
    virtual ~YourClass(){std::cout << "Hello form Destructor\n";}

 private:
     ~YourClass() {}

};
```

Finally you can call it like this:

```
#include "YourClass.hpp"

int main() {
    YourClass::getInstance().Hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Remember about compilation with -pthread flag

output:

Hello form YourClass

Hello form Destructor

Comment: You may get rid of `.get()` in `*m_instance.get();`. And you may also use Meyers' Singleton directly and remove `std::once_flag` and `std::unique_ptr` usage.